# Javascript get system background

Tags: javascript, background, get, system

I want to know if it is possible to get the system's background through javascript? I don't think it's possible but if it is, my next question is how to make the system background a background to a div.

Comment: the desktop background? impossible

Answer (score 1):

Because javascript is interpreted by the browser its impossible.You have better luck with some kind of a javascript engine such as Node or JavaScriptCore.

Comment: But a website can't make use of Node to get the client desktop background. (OP mentions setting the background of a div, so presumably we are talking about a web page here.)

Comment: @nnnnnn You can't presume its about a webpage. The div can be in the context of anything from a Cordova app to a cross OS application.

Comment: I think we can assume that it is _most likely_ a web page until the OP confirms otherwise. How else do you explain the first sentence of your own answer? But unless and until the OP provides more details we can't really tell them anything else.